# Get amount of distinct values across multiple columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using #standardSQL BigQuery and want to be able to count unique values across columns.

I want to count the number of distinct values across my user funnel per visit_id which are stored in the following columns: first_pgroup,second,third,forth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth.

**I have the following table:**

| visit_id | first_pgroup | second | third | forth | fifth | sixth | seventh | eighth | ninth | tenth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth | cloth |
| 2 | shoes | cloth | beauty |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | beauty |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | home&living | cloth | home&living | shoes | accessories |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | shoes | shoes | shoes | shoes | shoes | shoes |  |  |  |  |

**My goal is to be able to create a new column which states the unique values in each row.**

**The desired output is:**

[image]

Here is my query:

```
>        WITH
>             config AS (
>                 SELECT
>                 --SET time frame 
>                 DATE "2022-01-01" AS start_date,
>                 DATE "2022-01-01" AS end_date   ),
>         
>         
>         PDP_table AS (
>             SELECT
>             DISTINCT
>                 request_id AS request_id_PDP,
>                 eventType,
>                 SAFE_CAST(pid AS STRING) AS pid,
>                 SPLIT(pgroup , '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as product_group
>         
>             FROM
>                 `project.table`,
>                 config
>             WHERE
>                 DATE(PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN config.start_date
>                 AND config.end_date
>                 AND pid IS NOT NULL
>                 and eventType = "view" ),
>         
>        table AS (   SELECT
>             timestamp,
>             visit_id,
>             request_id,   FROM
>             `project.table.2`,
>             config   WHERE
>             DATE(PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN config.start_date
>               AND config.end_date
>               AND site IN ('Live2',
>                 'App'
>                 )AND country = 'de'),
>               raw as (   SELECT
>             cast((b.product_group) as string)  AS first_pgroup,
>             cast(LEAD( b.product_group, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id) as string) AS second,    cast( LEAD(
> b.product_group, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id)as
> string) AS third,
>             cast(LEAD( b.product_group, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id)as string) AS forth,
>             cast(LEAD( b.product_group, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id) as string) AS fifth,    cast( LEAD(
> b.product_group, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id)
> as string) AS sixth,  cast( LEAD( b.product_group, 6) OVER (PARTITION
> BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id) as string) AS seventh,    cast( LEAD(
> b.product_group, 7) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id
> )as string) AS eighth, cast( LEAD( b.product_group, 8) OVER (PARTITION
> BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id) as string) AS ninth,
>             cast(LEAD( b.product_group, 9) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY request_id) as string) AS tenth   FROM
>             table a   JOIN
>             PDP_table b   ON
>             b.request_id_PDP = a.request_id
>             )  
>              select *, (
>             select count(distinct category) - 1
>             from unnest(values(replace(to_json_string(t), 'null', '"null"'))) category
>             where category != 'null'   ) as category_count from raw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";
select *, (
    select count(distinct category) - 1
    from unnest(values(replace(to_json_string(t), 'null', '"null"'))) category
    where category != 'null'
  ) as category_count
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hey Mikhail, thank you very much for taking the time to help me. When using the solution directly into my query I receive this error: "Function not found: values at [65:17]"  Do I need to insert the colum names instead of values? And once I do that they cannot be called because there is no reference to the previous table. So I am not sure how to fix the error here

Comment: I posted my full query in the original question and included your snipped last.

Comment: sorry, copy/paste mistake. i missed pasting function definition. please see update in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Following approached worked based on Mikahils answer:

```
select *,  (select count(distinct category) from
   unnest([first_pgroup,second,third,forth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth,tenth])
     as category  where category != 'null') as cat_count from raw
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just sql to solve this, below approach is much simple and works across multiple databases

```
with main_table
as 
(select visit_id,first_group group_value from table
  union all
select visit_id,second_group from table
  union all
select visit_id,third_group from table
  union all
select visit_id,fourth_group from table
  union all
select visit_id,fifth_group from table
  union all
select visit_id,sixth_group from table
  union all
select visit_id,seventh_group from table)
select s.*,count(distinct m.group_value) distint_count
from main_table m
left join table s
   on m.visit_id=s.visit_id
```

Comment: Cool idea. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me find a solution!